# Python insert pandas series data in sql table

Tags: python, json, pandas, sql-insert, pyodbc

I'm trying to insert data into sql table whose datatype is of pandas.series.SO for which it gives me error
`ProgrammingError: ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=1 param-type=Series', 'HY105')`

Here is the code snippet

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import pyodbc
import json
import numpy as np
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('server connection')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute("select GEOCODE_ID, JSON from GEOCODE_TBL where JSON is NOT NULL AND GEOCODE_ID = 20")
ID=[]
JSON=""
for row in cursor.fetchall():
 ID.append(row[0]) 
 JSON=row[1]
data = json.loads(JSON)
result = json_normalize(data,'results')
def get_cols(st):
        pol = []
        for i in result['address_components'].apply(json_normalize):
             pol.append(','.join(i.apply(lambda x : x['long_name'] if st in x['types'] else np.nan,1).dropna()))
        return  pol

    result['country'] = get_cols('country') 
    result['room'] = get_cols('room') 
    result['premise'] = get_cols('premise')
sql = "UPDATE OTH_TBL SET GEOCODE_ID=?,country=?,room=?,premise=? where GEOCODE_ID=?"
param= (
   int(ID[0]),
   result['country'],
   result['room'],
   result['premise'],
   int(ID[0])
)
cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

the `type(result['country'])` is **pandas.core.series.Series** AND `type(ID[0])` is **int**

```
result['country']
Out[142]: 
0    India
1    India
2    India
3    India
4    India
5    India
6    India
7    India
8    India
9    India
Name: country, dtype: object
```

Does anyone has any idea about how could it be done.

Thanks..

Domnick

Comment: Try using the DataFrame.to_sql command http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Comment: @amanbirs Using the above method you suggested, it gives me error `DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')`

Comment: can you post what you tried? Looks like there was a problem with the connector you specified

Comment: Sorted: I was using `df.to_sql('[db_name].[dbo].[table_name]', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)` instead of  `df.to_sql('table_name', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)`

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion to go through that post, if you could post it as answer I would be able to upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataFrame.to_sql command should solve your problem

documentation here:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html